# Intellij IDEA: Rendering problems (Android)

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Edit: I should have included more info, so here's more stuff (if more is needed let me know):

Windows 10

Intellij 15.0.6.

Any/all options in the preview window have been tried with the same "Rendering Problems" dialog.

OK, so right now I'm getting this error when trying to display the xml preview window: Rendering Problems - This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of IntelliJ IDEA. Please update IntelliJ IDEA.

This question has been asked here a couple times before but I seem to be getting nowhere with those answers.

Intellij is at its latest version (determined from Help > Check for updates), everything in the Android SDK manager is up to date, and I've tried changing the preview window's API to a non-Preview API. Those three things were the old questions' answers. I don't know what to do next.

Here are the error details:

```
org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.RenderingException: This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of IntelliJ IDEA. Please update IntelliJ IDEA
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.LayoutLibraryLoader.load(LayoutLibraryLoader.java:90)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidTargetData.getLayoutLibrary(AndroidTargetData.java:180)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createTask(RenderService.java:163)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:640)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:585)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:580)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What is the exact version of Android Studio that you currently have running? What version of android and what device are you targeting for the preview?

Comment: I'm not using Android Studio, but my Intellij version is 15.0.6. build number IC-143.2370. API 23, and any device I choose doesn't work. I'm not specifically targeting any one device, but I am targeting smartphones in general.

Comment: Just a heads up `but I am targeting smartphones in general` is so broad, as if you were trying to compile the same source code for iOS / Android A,B,C....K,L,M,N) / Windows Phone / etc.. Try to be more specific on the target destination for your program. Finally, have you had any recent changes in the tool recently? Have you made any significant change in the project (or changed its folders). Try to be as specific as possible, with as much info possible for us to be able to understand the issue, and try to point a direction

Comment: Yes, I wasn't clear with that comment. I'm targeting Android API 17+. I haven't made any changes to structure, I've still got the same construction as I did when the preview window worked. The only thing I did differently was the amount of time spent on xml vs java code. When the preview last worked, I was spending equal time in xml as I was in Java. The last two weeks I've only been coding Java, so it was surprising when I finally came back to doing xml layout work and found this render problem. Surprising because I hadn't touched anything to do with layouts/preview window since it worked.

Comment: This is just a guess, but I think it's very possible that IntelliJ is not equipped to handle these previews by itself, but Android Studio would be able to.